# Split text in Excel cell when there is multiple deliminters

Tags: excel, formula, break

I have a list in a notepad that uses a comma for delimiter. The issue is this is the default and inside the second column( out of 2 columns) contains commas because its a few sentences each. How do I split the first and second column by the first comma in each row?

Ex:

```
Name, Info
----- ----
Parker, I have a dog by the name of Parker, and he loves to play dead. 
John Smith, John Smith married Elizabeth. Elizabeth has married on person before him, so this is now her second marriage.
```

Ps: this is not the actual information I have. Just an example.

I am looking for any advice with a formula to use in Excel or process if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place all the text in **A1** and in **B1** enter:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)-1)
```

and in **C1** enter:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+1,9999)
```

For example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks that works. If you don't mind, can you explain what the "+1,9999)" means?

Comment: @AlyssaCooke .....sure... **MID()** needs to know how many characters follow that first comma.  I don't know how many, so I put in a REALLY BIG NUMBER: *9999.*